# Fitting data to distributions in R: errors

Tags: r, error-handling, distribution

I'm fitting my data to several distributions in R. The goal is to see which distribution fits my data best. The code I'm using is based on: http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/distributions/fitting.html

```
my_data <- EP1sh

plotdist(my_data, histo = TRUE, demp = TRUE)

descdist(my_data, discrete=FALSE, boot=500)
fit_w  <- fitdist(my_data, "weibull")
fit_g  <- fitdist(my_data, "gamma")
fit_ln <- fitdist(my_data, "lnorm")
summary(fit_ln)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot.legend <- c("Weibull", "lognormal", "gamma")
denscomp(list(fit_w, fit_g, fit_ln), legendtext = plot.legend)
cdfcomp (list(fit_w, fit_g, fit_ln), legendtext = plot.legend)
qqcomp  (list(fit_w, fit_g, fit_ln), legendtext = plot.legend)
ppcomp  (list(fit_w, fit_g, fit_ln), legendtext = plot.legend)


fit = fitdistr(my_data, densfun="lognormal")
```

My dataframe is a single vector EP1sh, which has around 80 entries with a value between 1 and 6.

I keep getting the following errors. I first thought it was because I had several 'NA' in my dataframe, but I think I solved that and the problem remains (this was how i removed NA from EP1sh:)

```
EP1sh <- na.omit(EP1$Number_share)
EP1sh <- data.frame(EP1sh)
```

errors are:

> my_data <- EP1sh
>   plotdist(my_data, histo = TRUE, demp = TRUE)
>
> > Error in plotdist(my_data, histo = TRUE, demp = TRUE) : 
> >       data must be a numeric vector
>
> descdist(my_data, discrete=FALSE, boot=500)
>
> > Error in descdist(my_data, discrete = FALSE, boot = 500) : 
> >       data must be a numeric vector
>
> fit_w  <- fitdist(my_data, "weibull")
>
> > Error in fitdist(my_data, "weibull") : 
> >       data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1
>
> fit_g  <- fitdist(my_data, "gamma")
>
> > Error in fitdist(my_data, "gamma") : 
> >       data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1
>
> fit_ln <- fitdist(my_data, "lnorm")
>
> > Error in fitdist(my_data, "lnorm") : 
> >       data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1
>
> summary(fit_ln)
>
> > Error in summary(fit_ln) : object 'fit_ln' not found

Any ideas would be great !

Comment: Can you define `EP3` for us?

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for the speedy response. I saw that in this post I accdentally wrote EP3 where I meant EP1sh. Will fix it in the question above, thanks!

Comment: Thanks - for testing I have defined `EP1sh <- rep(1:6, 80/6)` and get no errors.  What returns on your end with `str(EP1sh)`?

Comment: @ErikKornet I changed the question. Saw that I had some other name referral sloppiness in my R code so the errors have changed with the edit.

Comment: @ErikKornet Thanks - `str(EP1sh)` returns 
> str(EP1sh) 'data.frame': 83 obs. of  1 variable: $ EP1sh: atomic  2 6 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...   ..- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  int [1:88] 1 6 8 14 18 21 23 25 28 30 ...`

Comment: Ok - please try re-defining `EP1sh` as follows: `EP1sh <- as.vector(EP1sh$EP1sh)`

Comment: Great! This works. So the problem is that this code does not run for a dataframe, even when you define a vector of the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, the functions require numeric vectors, not data frames.  The error messages in this case are a good clue - and you can always use `str()` for any object to determine its definition, and whether or not there is a mismatch between how it is defined and what is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `plotdist()`, `descdist()`, `fitdist()`, and `fitdistr()` functions you need to specify a vector, for example `my_data$Number_share` instead of the entire data frame `my_data`; that's assuming your "column" name is `Number_share`, so modify accordingly. This should hopefully fix your issue!